# How to randomise rendered frame

Tags: rendering

Is there are way to render frames randomly from inside the blender interface?

I'm rendering for a project being coordinated over dropbox, the dropbox synx isn't as fast as I'd like and even with the overwrite setting off, we keep rendering the same frames. Randomly allocating frames will (at least initially) cut down on overwrite.

[image: overwrite is off]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way to render a frame randomly - built-into Blender,
*although it wouldn't be so hard to write this as a Python script.*

However using no-overwrite with an online file-system seems like asking for troubles, in this case its probably worth looking into some kind of render-farm software.

---

If you know the total number of computers beforehand, you could give each its own frame-offset from the start and use a frame step, so they're not going to re-write each-others files.

See the `--frame-jump` and `--frame-start` option, to offset relative to the frame start.
 https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#command-line-arguments

Comment: OR is there any way of rendering backwards? Sadly we haven't got the webserver space for a render farm